# Split words from datraframe by space to rows while duplicating the info from other columns ( python,pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rows

[image]I have a df which is composed by 5 columns one being a comment column where people leave a comment.

What I would like to do is split that comment column by space into multiple rows while duplicating the other columns:

df:

| r_id | start | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | i am the text that needs splitting by space to rows |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | hello hello |

wanted result:

| r_id | start | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | i |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | am |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | the |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | text |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | hello |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | hello |

I've tried anything from `str.split()` to regex without result.

-- le with code:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower() if x.dtype == "object" else x) 
(df
 .assign(comments=df['comments'].str.split())
 .explode('comments')
)
print(df)

df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace('ă','a')
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace('â','a')
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace('î','i')
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace('ș','s')
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace('ț','t')
df.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ',regex=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

yet it wouldn't  split the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df2 = (df
 .assign(comments=df['comments'].str.split())
 .explode('comments')
)
```

output:

```
   r_id        start    comments
0      1  2021-01-01           i
0      1  2021-01-01          am
0      1  2021-01-01         the
0      1  2021-01-01        text
0      1  2021-01-01        that
0      1  2021-01-01       needs
0      1  2021-01-01   splitting
0      1  2021-01-01          by
0      1  2021-01-01       space
0      1  2021-01-01          to
0      1  2021-01-01        rows
1      2  2021-01-02       hello
1      2  2021-01-02       hello
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately it doesn t spilt it :|

df.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ',regex=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

 
(df
 .assign(comments=df['comments'].str.split())
 .explode('comments')
)
print(df) --- and it wouldnt split the text

Comment: @hectic can you update the example in the question? comments are not really good for code

Comment: edited  the question and added a screenshot

Comment: @hectic I don't see the the difference, you said "*What I would like to do is split that comment column by space into multiple rows while duplicating the other columns*", isn't it what my code is doing? Can you edit the expected output?

Comment: i posted a screenshot with that the code is doing, and unfortunately it does not split the text...which for some reason got posted on top of the question...

Comment: @hectic did you assign the output of my code? ;) Check the update, I made it explicit